# Browser-sync cannot get error

Tags: npm, browser-sync

I am following this tutorial:
https://css-tricks.com/why-npm-scripts/
Really found it useful. But I added in the script for browser-sync and it never calls to my index.html file that is inside src and dist folders. From my root I have the following package.json script portion:

```
"scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src",
    "autoprefixer": "postcss -u autoprefixer -r dist/css/*",
    "lint": "eslint src/js",
    "uglify": "mkdir -p dist/js &amp;&amp; uglifyjs src/js/*.js -m -o dist/js/app.js &amp;&amp; uglifyjs src/js/*.js -m -c -o dist/js/app.min.js",
    "imagemin": "imagemin src/images dist/images -p",
    "serve": "browser-sync start  --files 'dist/styles/*.css, dist/js/*.js'",
    "build:css": "npm run scss && npm run autoprefixer",
    "build:js": "npm run lint &amp;&amp; npm run uglify",
    "build:all": "npm run build:css && npm run build:js && npm run build:imagemin",
    "watch:css": "onchange 'src/*.scss' -- npm run build:css",
  "watch:js": "onchange 'src/js/*.js' -- npm run build:js",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell 'npm run serve' 'npm run watch:css' 'npm run watch:js'"
  },
```

Can someone explain to me how it knows to run the index file?  I know it builds a server out of the root folder, but my package.json is not inside the dist folder?

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the documentation.

```
"serve": "browser-sync start --server --files 'dist/*' --startPath 'dist'"
```

startPath allowed me to tell it what folder to use as the root.